# Searching for string in a two dimensional array vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2D array in the following format. (Unsure how to format this so it appears in a table format. The first and second columns are 1 character each and the 3rd columns is 2 characters)

```
a  1  aa
a  2  ab
b  1  ba
b  2  bb
c  1  ca
c  2  cb
d  1  da
d  2  db
e  1  ea
e  2  eb
f  1  fa
f  2  fb
```

I need to first search for "c" in the first column. If that is found, I need to search for "2" in the second and find the corresponding value in the 3rd. In this case, I finally need the value "cb".

Here is what I have so far but it isn't working correctly since I don't see the desired results

```
Public Sub Readinto_array()

Dim TheArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim found As Boolean

TheArray = Range("G20:I31").Value

found = False
For i = LBound(TheArray) To UBound(TheArray)
    For j = LBound(TheArray, 2) To UBound(TheArray, 2)
        MsgBox TheArray(i, j)
        If TheArray(i, j) <> "c" Then
           Exit For
        Else
           If StrComp(TheArray(i, j + 1), "2", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               MsgBox "found"
               found = True
               Exit For
           End If
        End If
     Next j
     If found Then
        Exit For
     End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the j+1 simply needs to be j+2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have to loop for the columns since you know there's always 3...
So this seems easier.

```
Public Sub Readinto_array()

Dim TheArray As Variant
Dim i As Long 

TheArray = Range("G20:I31").Value

For i = LBound(TheArray) To UBound(TheArray)
    If TheArray(i, 1) = "c" And TheArray(i, 2) = "2" Then
        MsgBox (TheArray(i, 3))
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Or further simplified using innate excel objects.

```
Public Sub Readinto_array()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("G20:I31")
    For Each cell In MyRange
      If cell.Value = "c" And Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1) = "2" Then
        MsgBox (Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 2).Value)
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the first time using arrays. Guess got a little bit confused looking at the examples.

Comment: @rajeev Not a problem.  Sometimes you have to step back from the weeds to see if there's an easier method.  You didn't have to use the array.

Comment: If the data range is very large, it will be faster to use arrays than to iterate the worksheet object.  Both will work, it's just a matter of performance.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert. As mentioned by David the data range is a little bit larger. Using your first solution worked great !!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a worksheet formula.  For example, if E1 contains your column1 value; and B1 your column2 value, try:

```
G2: =INDEX(ThirdColumn,SUMPRODUCT((FirstColumn=E1)*(SecondColumn=E2)*ROW(ThirdColumn)))
```

[image]

Comment: I knew the function sumproduct was there. Never found a practical way to use it until I saw your function

Answer (score 1):

I see a tree like structure and think xml but to keep it simple use a Dictionary...

In the VBA Editor - using the Tools/References menu add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Write a function to create the dictionary:

```
Public Function LookErUp() As Dictionary

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim d As Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary

    Dim col1() As Variant
    col1 = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

    Dim col2 As Dictionary
    For i = 0 To UBound(col1)
        Set col2 = New Dictionary
        col2.Add 1, col1(i) & "a"
        col2.Add 2, col1(i) & "b"
        d.Add col1(i), col2
    Next

    Set LookErUp = d

End Function
```

You can test using the dictionary the Test procedure:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim ld As Dictionary
    Set ld = LookErUp

    If ld.Exists("c") Then
        If ld("c").Exists(2) Then
            MsgBox "Found " & ld("c")(2)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is new for me. Never knew of that one before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a third column where you concatenate the values from three previous columns i.e. in **D1** you would have `=A1&B1&C1`. Next use that in you **vlookup** or **match**. If you do not specify exact match then in case having multiple entries for **c 1** you would get the first or last one, depending on comparison type used.